# WP_Query() with custom post type and taxonomy -- get all terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query

I have the following

- custom post type: `lesson`
- custom Taxonomy: `subject`

  - which contains terms like `math`, `reading`, etc.)

I have configured my page so that the user may filter the results by entering a taxonomy "subject" as a query variable:

`http://www.myWebsiteURL.com/lessons&lc=study-skills`

This works great for getting a single taxonomy category, however I am having difficulty getting ALL taxonomy categories in a single request (ie for an overview/unfiltered page).

Here is how I'm building my query:

```
<?php
    /* if URL query value is a valid category, get all lessons for that category.
       If it is not a valid category (or not category is provided), get ALL lessons. */

    $args = ["post-type"=>"lesson", "post-status" => "publish"];
    $validCats = ['study-skills','time-management','math','tutoring','reading','online-learning'];
    if ( isset($_GET['lc']) && in_array($_GET['lc'], $validCats) ) {
        $args["subject"] = $_GET['lc'];
    } else {
        $arg["subject"] = "*"; // ??? what goes here?
    }
    $lessons = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Comment: How does your URL looks for all taxonomy terms?

Comment: Have you tried `lc[]=study-kills&lc[]=math-is-great`? That would be equal to form fields with a name of `name="lc[]"`.

Comment: I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types UI plugins to create my post types/taxonomy, if that's any help. I'm not sure exactly what you mean, @kaiser

Comment: @PieterGoosen it should just be `/lessons` to get all the taxonomy terms. Thats what I need help figuring out

Comment: And that gives you a 404

Comment: @PieterGoosen no, it just takes me to the "lessons" page with "No Results found". thats the part i need help with. `/lessons` should display all the taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a full proper [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) here. The `{tax}` syntax is depreciated according to the docs

A `tax_query` is also better here as you will be dealing with an array of terms. When your URL is

```
http://www.myWebsiteURL.com/lessons
```

this means that all terms should be displayed. So this means that you need to use the full `$validCats` array as query terms.

With this in mind, I have slightly changed your code to the following: (*CAVEAT: Untested, and I assume you are using term slugs here, so I have set the `field` parameter accordingly*)

```
<?php
    /* if URL query value is a valid category, get all lessons for that category.
       If it is not a valid category (or not category is provided), get ALL lessons. */

    $validCats = ['study-skills', 'time-management', 'math', 'tutoring', 'reading', 'online-learning'];

    if ( isset( $_GET['lc'] ) && in_array( $_GET['lc'], $validCats ) ) {
        $terms = $_GET['lc'];
    } else {
        $terms = $validCats;
    }

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = [
        'post_type'   => 'lesson', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged'       => $paged,
        'tax_query'   => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'subject',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $terms
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $lessons = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! One last question (wp newbie here :) ) -- how can I modify the WP_Query you've provided to allow for pagination?

Comment: Glad it works :-). I have updated my code to include pagination. Just a note that I did not inclue, if you are going to use `next_posts_link()`, you should add `$lessons->max_num_pages` as second parameter to `next_posts_link()`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the tip. Pagination is working great!

Comment: Great. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Oh! One last thing --- do you know how I can integrate this with Jetpack plugin Infinite Scroll? I have it working for my main (default) query for blog posts, however I'm not sure how to get it working with this custom query.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I haven't yet worked with Jetpack. But I believe doing a search on the jetpack site might help you in the right direction. Just one last thing, if it works with the main query, it should work with a custom one too. Rememer to set the variables accordingly, the main query uses `$wp_query`, you should just replace this with your query variable which is `$lessons`. Good luck :-)